# Sql Table Doesnt Map to Datagrid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datagrid, database-connection

I have a Table dbo.MSreplication_options using connectionString, i am trying to map this table to datagrid1.DataSource.

```
SqlConnection cnn;
SqlCommand con;
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["masterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    cnn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    con = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.MSreplication_options");
    con.Connection = cnn;
    ds = new DataSet();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(con);
    cnn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cnn.Close();
    DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].ToString();
}
```

web config

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="masterConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=node39\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

At runtime it doesnt map to datagrid1? what particular mistake am i doing?

Comment: You don't need to do 
`cnn.Open();
da.Fill(ds);
cnn.Close();`
As SqlDataAdapter uses disconnected architecture of ADO.net, instead just write `da.Fill(ds);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `DataGrid1.DataBind();`

In addition to this the `Memory Management` is not being taken care of.

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["masterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
{
    con = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.MSreplication_options");
    con.Connection = cnn;
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(con);
        cnn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cnn.Close();
        DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].ToString();
        DataGrid1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this after DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].ToString();

```
DataGrid1.DataBind()
```

Comment: And like in Kanavis post you want to make sure your objects are being disposed properly